# How do I change the color texview if a record is not null?

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I put that if the record notes and null 
remains white while the TextView if it is not to red?
I tried so but I do not work

```
 String notes = notesName.get(pos);
 if (notes  != null ) {
     mHolder.txt_notes.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
 } else {   
     mHolder.txt_notes.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String Notes = notesName.get(pos);
    if (Notes.length() != 0 ){
        mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
    } else{  
        mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

or

```
mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String Notes = notesName.get(pos);
        if (Notes  != null && !Notes.isEmpty() )
                        mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
                     else  
                    mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: if I put: if (notes! = null &&! ​​Notes.isEmpty ()), 
isEmpty by mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry but it seemed to work properly, I noticed that when I scroll the listview, even if there is nothing in Notes, I texview other colors in listview, obviously something is wrong, 
if you restart the display adapter resumes operation 
it seems that with the scolling would need a refresh

Answer (score 0):

```
 String Notes = notesName.get(pos);
    if (!Notes.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
                } else  
                mHolder.txt_notes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```